# Wordpress Legacy Code Takeover

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, localhost, mamp

So,

I've been tasked with taking over a word press project from 2012. I've been given all the source code, in addition to a database dump, and have installed MAMP.

First, I was getting the common "Error establishing a database connection". When I looked at `localhost:8888` I saw that the database was not found. Hence, I created a database from the name given in my `wp-config.php` and all was well; or so I thought.

I'm stuck now between two situations:

1) I only create a database with the desired name and perform no import, at which point I receive a prompt to install WordPress giving me a barebones installation using none of the legacy code.

2) I import the the database dump into the appropriately named database, and nothing works.`localhost:8888` cannot be found and `wp-admin` redirects to the live sites admin login.

Hopefully someone can help to figure out how to run this site locally so I can make the desired changes for the client.

Lastly, I should also note that I've attempted to update the `wp_options` table to have the appropriate url of `http://localhost:8888` and still no luck. I've also tried visiting `localhost` and `http://localhost:8888` and none of these work either.

Thanks!

Comment: What if you set the url in database to just localhost? Without the port.

Comment: Sadly no luck with this approach. It seems like for some reason when dumping in the database WordPress does not know how to serve the new files..

Comment: If you can actually connect to the database it should just be a url issue.

Comment: I wonder what the url should be, as the `wp-admin` redirects to the live page's admin login page.

Comment: That sounds like you haven't replaced all references to the old url. This must be your problem after all.

Comment: Could you advise on how I could accomplish this, or point me to an article in the right direction? (PS thank you for you continued support and quick responses!)

Comment: Check out the docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: So I have tried editing the lines within my `wp-config.php` with no luck and have even tried issuing the sql command from php admin:

`UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://localhost/test-site', 'http://localhost:8888') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://localhost/test-site', 'http://localhost:8888');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://localhost/test-site','http://localhost:8888');`

Where `test-site` was the ip address of hosting. Still nothin

Comment: what are the errors you're getting? make sure all error display is turned on

Comment: So with `WP_DEBUG` set to `True` I'm only getting notices, no errors. Furthermore, these only appear when I attempt to visit `wp-admin` and not when I visit the default `localhost` url.

Comment: Is your localhost definitely pointing to the proper folder and index file? Can you troubleshoot by just adding an index.html and trying to visit that? Troubleshoot your setup.

Comment: So if I add an `index.html` to the folder being pointed at by MAMP nothing loads.. perhaps this is indicative of a deeper issue?

Comment: Maybe. Move your wp stuff out for a second, have just an empty folder with index.html. Until that works I wouldn't worry about WP.

Comment: Created new folder, simple `index.html` restarted MAMP pointed it to the new directory.. nothing

simple `index.php` MAMP pointed as this new directory.. nothing..

Comment: Well, now we know where the problem lies.

Comment: Ready? So fresh install and with `index.html` doesn't load with `http://localhost:8888` but does load with `http://localhost:8888//`.

Then, (just to add some interesting) when I remove the `index.html` I get nothing. Blank page. Even trying `http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/` nothing. 

So back to square 1 ?

Comment: Well if you remove index then nothing should be loading....Unless I misunderstand.

Comment: I've been placing `index.html` in the same folder as the old webpage with this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, as discussed in comments, this is an issue with MAMP setup and not WP configuration.